# How to add bounty for a question?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to add bounty to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401521/qmy-approach-for-replacing-current-ubuntu-13-04-with-ubuntu-13-10) Q but I don't find an option for the same in the Q. How to do that please?

I also checked "https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty" but couldn't get a reason (Have I overlooked on this help page?).

Comment: marco beat you to it >:)

Answer (score 3):

[You need 75 reputation to start bounties](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). That's the problem.